# how to post xml formate request in url on submit button click

Tags: javascript, php, xml

**My Form**

```
<form action="test.php" name="form" method="post">
  <label>msisdn :-</label>
  <input type="text" name="msisdn" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>command :-</label>
  <input type="text" name="command" value="getimis" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>username :-</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>password :-</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

=> how to post xml request in submit button in this url `http://206.190.228.185/vl/vl_api_bill.php`

=> in this formate xml request send to submit button click in post url  ..

**Request**

```
<bill-request>
  <msisdn>123456789</msisdn>
  <command>getimsi</command>
  <username>bob</username>
  <password>dcba</password>
</bill-request>
```

**Response**

```
<bill-response>
  <status>success</status>
  <msg>123456789</msg>
</bill-response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot send xml data directly from html form.You can do this using jquery ajax.

Add onclick to submit button, stop the default event and using jquery ajax post xml data

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="funcName(event)"/>

<script>

function funcName()
{
event.preventDefault();
var msisdn = document.getElementsByName("msisdn")[0].value;
var command = document.getElementsByName("command")[0].value;
var username = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
var data = '<bill-request><msisdn>' + msisdn + '</msisdn><command>' + command   + '</command><username>' + username  + '</username> <password>' + password  + '</password></bill-request>';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/xml;',
    success: function (response) {},
    error: function (ex) {}
  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: how to create xml data ??

Comment: plz help me bro how to create xml data and how to use in function ..

Comment: updated my answer. have a look. Since its not much complicated, I have done it manually,

Comment: thx bro . let be try ok ..

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms can send data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (which is compact), `multipart/form-data` format (which supports file uploads) or `text/plain` format (which has no practical use that isn't better served with other tools).

XML is not an option.

If you need to send XML from the browser then you have to use JavaScript. You can extract the data from a form using DOM, build your XML and then use the XMLHttpRequest object to send it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following code

```
  <?php

        error_reporting(0);

        function to_xml($arr,$wrapper = 'bill-request',$cycle = 1)
        {

          $new_line = "\n";


          if($cycle == 1) { $output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'.$new_line; }
          $output.= tabify($cycle - 1).'<'.$wrapper.'>'.$new_line;
          foreach($arr as $key => $val)
          {
            if(!is_array($val))
            {
              $output.= tabify($cycle).'<'.htmlspecialchars($key).'>'.$val.'</'.htmlspecialchars($key).'>'.$new_line;
            }
            else
            {
              $output.= print_r_xml($val,$key,$cycle + 1).$new_line;
            }
          }
          $output.= tabify($cycle - 1).'</'.$wrapper.'>';


          return $output;
        }


        function tabify($num_tabs)
        {
          for($x = 1; $x <= $num_tabs; $x++) { $return.= "\t"; }
          return $return;
        }

        $xml= to_xml($_POST);

        print_r($xml);
        ?>

        <form name="form" method="post">
            <label > msisdn :- </label>
            <input type="text" name="msisdn"  /><br><br>
            <label> command :- </label>
            <input type="text" name="command" value="getimis" /><br><br>
            <label> username :- </label>
            <input type="text" name="name"  /><br><br>
            <label> password :- </label>
            <input type="text" name="password"  /><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: i need xml request bro . like this   <bill-request>
     <msisdn>123456789</msisdn>
     <command>getimsi</command>
     <username>bob</username>
     <password>dcba</password>
    </bill-request>

Comment: after submit the form  press ctrl+u you can see whatever you want bro. its depend on you how can you mange

Comment: @ramsingh — The question is asking how to send XML from the form to the server, not how to convert what the form sends to XML *after* it gets to the server.